# How to get image coordinates after centering the object using image.centerObject() in fabric js

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am drawing a rectangle on top of a image and then saving the coordinates of both to a Mysql Database table.

Then I have to retrieve the same image and overlaying Rectangle from a Andriod APP
 which will not know anything on FabricJS . 
It will only know the coordinates of image and rectangle.
Luckily for image it is not a problem as it can be maintained using some Aspect ratio algorithm.
But how to get the coordinates of Rectangle , so that it can be rendered correctly.

Now what I see is Fabricjs saves the coordinates according to window left ,top, width, height. But andriod app expects the coordinates according to image , which fabricjs doesn't provide.

Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Please let me know if somebody didn't understand .
Its a basic and easy statement , hence not adding any fiddle or code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before saving to database do this:

```
image.setCoords();
rect.setCoords();
```

in

```
image.oCoords.tl, image.oCoords.tr, image.oCoords.bl, image.oCoords.br
```

and

```
rect.oCoords.tl, rect.oCoords.tr, rect.oCoords.bl, rect.oCoords.br
```

you will find 4 objects with both x and y coordinates that represent your absolute position of the object.
`tl` stands for `Top Left`, `br` stands for `Bottom Right` and so on.

You should have no problem then to make some subtraction and find relative coordinates of the two objects.

**Example:**

if image has `tl (45,80)` and rect has `tl (80,110)` it means that rect coordinate relative to image is `(80-45, 110-80)` = `(35, 30)`

Comment: no, that gives coordinates according to screen , not to images. Android team takes care of rendering image using some Aspect ratio. So, I can't force them to use **image.oCoords.tl, image.oCoords.tr, image.oCoords.bl, image.oCoords.br**

Comment: Those are position relative to canvas origin (0, 0) not screen. This is the only ready data you can retrieve from fabricjs canvas to re render same situation somewhere else.

Comment: Answer satisfies the scope and gave me few hints to accomplish my work. Hence, accepting it.  Thanks. <br/> I have another question for how to know whether you are re-sizing on which axis (tl, tr, bl , br) . Any idea on this?

Comment: during canvas.on("object:resizing") check the target originx and originy. you are usually resizing by thr opposite corner. Also in newer fabricjs version there is a variable that will tell you this. have to find out.